# Styling hyperlinked images in css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply anchor tags to an image I had already styled in css by pushing it to the right (using `text-align: right` on its containing `div`) and resizing it from 400px to 25px:

**css**:

```
.instagram-section {
    text-align: right;
    font-family: 'Life Savers', cursive;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.ig-logo {
    height: 25px;
}
```

But I'm finding that all this styling is lost on the image once it's surrounded in `<a>` tags:

**html** (before anchor tags applied to image):

```
<div class="instagram-section">
    <strong>... my <a href="https://www.instagram.com/myinstagram/">Instagram</strong></a>
    <!-- <a href="https://www.instagram.com/myinstagram/"> -->
    <img src="/img/icons/instagram/instagram-logo-400.png" class="ig-logo">
    <!-- </a> -->
</div>
```

[image]

**html** (after anchor tags applied to image):

```
<div class="instagram-section">
    <strong>... my <a href="https://www.instagram.com/myinstagram/">Instagram</strong></a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/myinstagram/">
    <img src="/img/icons/instagram/instagram-logo-400.png" class="ig-logo">
    </a>
</div>
```

[image]

I'm a bit new to html/css and haven't been able to find much on the internet apart from using an image already the size I want. This is fine, but I also need the image to appear on the same line as the text and also aligned to the right.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: `.ig-logo, a .ig-logo { height: 25px; }`? Although having made that suggestion I honestly don't see anything obvious in your posted CSS that would cause the difference you show.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't seem to work for me. I did manage to stumble on something that worked (always the way after posting a question on SO!)

Answer (score 0):

Playing around a bit, this seemed to work:

```
.instagram-section {
    text-align: right;
    font-family: 'Life Savers', cursive;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.instagram-section a img.ig-logo{
    height: 25px;
    display: inline;
}
```

Don't know if it's the best method, so welcome better answers.